# Separating specific HTML code from another code

Tags: php, html

I don't really know how to ask this properly. What I'm doing in my site is loading an article from database, which is designed with direct HTML codes. So, in case the code wasn't written properly, I want to prevent it from rendering other elements which are outside the article. Is that possible by declaring new HTML element or something similar?

Comment: Take a look at the `<iframe>` element and at utilities to tidy up html markup like `tidyhtml`.

Comment: This is a more difficult problem than you might expect. A simple method might be to remove all HTML tags that aren't in a whitelist of allowed tags (i.e. strong, em, etc). I'd recommend finding a library to do this for you, as it is incredibly difficult to do this kind of thing safely (["samy is my hero"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_(computer_worm)) comes to mind...)

Comment: iframe is used to embed another HTML document, which in my case I echo it from the php when loading the page, and not including another file.